# TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name <name>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this example code:

```js
function myFunction(base: string): typeof getter {
 function getter(contactInfo: ContactInfo): Address[] {
   ...
   return address;
 }
 
 return getter;
}

export default myFunction;
```

But when I try to do a build with declaration files, I have the following error:

> error TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'getter'.
> 23 function myFunction(base: string): typeof getter {

I can fix it adding the type of `getter` instead of `typeof`:

```js
function myFunction(base: string): (contactInfo: ContactInfo) => Address[] {
 function getter(contactInfo: ContactInfo): Address[] {
   ...
   return address;
 }

 return getter;
}

export default myFunction;
```

But there are some files that are more complicated than this. There is a way to avoid this error using `typeof getter` instead of passing all the types?

Comment: More complicated, in what way?

Comment: You might want to just `export default (base: string) => (contactInfo: ContactInfo) => Address[] { … return address; };`, using anonymous arrow functions only

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to handle this is to remove the function type. TypeScript is smart enough to infer the return type of the function without an explicit notation.

```js
function myFunction(base: string) {
 function getter(contactInfo: ContactInfo): Address[] {   
   return address;
 }
 
 return getter;
}

export default myFunction;  
// inferred type is: 
// function myFunction(base: string): (contactInfo: ContactInfo) => Address[]
```

Comment: But then I get a eslint error: `Missing return type on function eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` :(